# Efficient and safe storage of string pairs C++

Tags: c++, string, save, file-management

I am making a volume (voxel) based terrain generation engine using polyvox, and will be need to store lots of volume information. The Polyvox library makes it easy to pull out the values. However the large number of chunks, makes it infeasible to store each chunk as a separate file.

It would likely be easiest to pull out the volume information with a hexadecimal number for the chunk id, and a string for the volume information, but how do I store this information efficiently?

I have considered databases (really wanted to use Tokyo Cabinet!), but I have not found any libraries for c++, that are compatible with windows, that fit my needs. Also databases can be susceptible to corruption, and I would like to protect the user's world data as much as possible.

Does anyone have a thought on how to organize and save this information effectively? I have been pulling my hair out all day on this one. Does anyone know any good libraries that could help?

Thank you!

Comment: Numbers are just numbers - not hexadecimal or otherwise ;-).  You're not providing crucial details, such as: will your numbers be contiguous or nearly so?  Will your chunks be fixed size, one of a few sizes, totally variable sizes?

Comment: "Also databases can be susceptible to corruption"... and you have some persistence method that's not?

Answer (score 0):

kyoto cabinet.

http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/

Alternativly, [boost interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_map) seems to have map container which may solve your problem.